# Overriding Base class not working properly

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm trying to override a base class like this in C++

```
class A:
    QWidget *getWidget();

class B: public A:
    using A::getWidget;
    QWidget *getWidget();
```

When I try to use this:

```
A *test = new B();
test->getWidget();
```

Here, the widget from class A is returned. Is there a way to get widget B? Since I don't want to start with inspecting my class and casting down to B to get the correct widget, I want to be able to use it similar to the above code snippet. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you should declare `getWidget()` as `virtual` if you want dynamic polymorphic resolution of your function call. That should solve the particular problem you are addressing.

Secondly, the `using A::getWidget` is useless, because you are importing `A`'s function `getWidget()` into the scope of `B`, which already defines a function with the same name and signature.

Answer (score 1):

Is that C++ code?

```
class A
{
public:
    //you need the virtual keyword here
    virtual QWidget *getWidget();
    virtual ~A();
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    //you need using to overload a method from the base class, it's not needed for override
    QWidget *getWidget();
};

A *test = new B();
test->getWidget();
delete test;
```

LE: also don't forget a virtual destructor in the base class.